# How to use volatile in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I tried something like this:

```
private volatile var instanceState: InstanceState = InstanceState.starts

Error:  'Expected member declaration'
```

and like this:

```
private volatile var instanceState: InstanceState = InstanceState.starts

Error:  'Property getter or setter expected'
```

Volatile not supported on Kotlin ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can mark a property as `volatile` with [@Volatile](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-volatile/) annotation:

```
@Volatile var name:String = "stack"
```

The resulting field declaration is equivalent to Java's:

```
private volatile java.lang.String name;
```

As per the [@Volatile](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-volatile/) docs:

> Marks the JVM backing field of the annotated property as volatile,
>   meaning that writes to this field are immediately made visible to
>   other threads.

Comment: the annotation should be on the same line, I think

Comment: @voddan is that some recommended Kotlin style guide?

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin does not have a `volatile` keyword but an annotation: `@Volatile` (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-volatile/)